# Displaying and randomizing sprites in a 4x6 grid - Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am trying to setup a card matching game. I have a vector that holds 16 unique cards. I am trying to make it randomize the card vector but only select the first 12 cards and create a 4x6 grid for a total of 24 matching pairs on the board. I have the cards vector populated but I'm not sure how to create the grid so the cards are spaced out within the grid. And I'm not sure how to shuffle the cards vector so it is different each time. Also, I am using Cocos2d-x 3.2. Thanks for any advice.

```
std::vector<Sprite*> cards;
std::vector<std::string> cardNames = { "0.png", "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png", "6.png", "7.png", "8.png", "9.png", "10.png", "11.png", "12.png", "13.png", "14.png", "15.png" };

for (int n = 0; n < cardNames.size(); n++)
{
    auto sprite = Sprite::create(cardNames.at(n));

    sprite->setPosition(cocos2d::Point((50 * (n + 1)), 20));
    sprite->setTag(n);

    cards.push_back(sprite);

    addChild(sprite);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int n = 0; n <= 15; n++)
             // ^^^^^^^
```

looks pretty wrong for me, as for the traditional conventions.

Why not simply

```
for (int n = 0; n < cardNames.size(); n++)
```

instead?

---

Regarding *how to shuffle*, see [`std::shuffle` et al](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) please.

Comment: I tried using the std::shuffle, but couldn't get it to work for vector<sprites>. That shuffle works for like primitives but I'm not sure how to use it for a cocos2dx vector of sprites.